# Execute MySQL Query asynchronously⁯ inside loop C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have predefined `ExecuteMySqlQuery(string tableName)` and `ExecuteMySqlQueryAsync(string tableName)` methods.

I want to implement `void ExecuteCustomQuerySync(List<string> tables)` and `Task ExecuteCustomQueryASync(List<string> tables)` methods.

For the first one, it is simply:

```
void ExecuteCustomQuerySync(List<string> tables)
{
    if (tables.IsNullOrEmpty()) return;
    foreach(var table in tables) 
    {
        // some code1
        ExecuteMySqlQuery(table);
        // some code2
    }
}
```

For the later one, I'm not sure what is the correct option:

Option1. Use the previous `ExecuteCustomQuerySync` inside `Task.Run`:

```
Task ExecuteCustomQueryASync(List<string> tables)
{
    if (tables.IsNullOrEmpty()) return Task.CompletedTask;
    return Task.Run(() => ExecuteCustomQuerySync(tables));
}
```

Option2. Use predefined `ExecuteMySqlQueryAsync` in for loop and return `Task.WhenAll` :

```
Task ExecuteCustomQueryASync(List<string> tables)
{
    if (tables.IsNullOrEmpty()) return Task.CompletedTask;
    List<Task> tasks = new();
    foreach(var table in tables) 
    {
        // some code1
        tasks.Add(ExecuteMySqlQueryAsync(table));
        // some code2
    }
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

In Option1, the implementation is shorter and I don't have to refactor `// some code1` and `// some code2` to call them in the the new custom methods.

Anyway, I'd go with Option2 if it is the correct one.

I've tried both Options, both are valid, but I'm not sure what is the elegant and correct one in terms of `Task` coding style and usage!

Comment: Option 2 looks correct, but also show `ExecuteMySqlQueryAsync` implementation.

Comment: I would be most worried about *behavior* than *style*! The `Task.WhenAll` will bombard the database with all the queries at once (unless the `ExecuteMySqlQueryAsync` has a synchronous implementation). Your database might not be grateful for this!